# Ordering the function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, .when

I have to call the functions in an order, but somehow they work independently.

Here are the functions:

```
function a(){
  Ajax_Call_1();
}

function b(){
  Ajax_Call_2();
}

function c(){
  Ajax_Call_3();
}

$.when( a() ).then( $.when( b() ).then( c() ) );
```

When I run it, it looks like:

> A works
>
> C works
>
> B works

But sometimes:

> C works
>
> A works
>
> B works

How can I order them?

Comment: `then` is supposed to take a function so that it can execute it when the asynchronous operation completes. The way you wrote it, you're just executing all 3 functions as quickly as possible.

Comment: people still prefer jquery over promises? weird.

Comment: `a().then(b).then(c)` ? All three have to return `$.ajax` or whatever.

Comment: @GottZ jQuery uses Promises ([jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) is based on CommonJS Promises/A...

Comment: @GottZ I am open to any solution if you suggest

Comment: @georg thank you, I gonna try

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I believe GottZ means it's odd that people use jQuery's promises instead of native ones since they're supported just about everywhere now.

Comment: @MikeC I guess... I generally use the functionality built into the library/framework I'm using at the time (to keep the code more consistent), but that's me.

Comment: @NewPHPer well i don't know how your actual function works. all i do know is how promises work and your code does not imply how and when it fires their resolve events. well anyways.. it has been solved already as i can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain promise-like objects with using `then` method. Note the difference between `then` and `done/fail`, a *done* callback passed to `then` can return a new promise-like object for the rest of the control flow. This is why you can do the chaining. See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/).

```
a().then(b).then(c).done(function() { // the last promise has been resolved });
```

All of your functions should `return` the promise object for this to work. So your `b` should look like this.

```
function b(){
  return Ajax_Call_2();
}
```

Where `Ajax_Call` itself should return the `ajax` call, like `return $.ajax(...)`.

Note that as both `b` and `c` returns the promise, you can pass them directly to `then`.

Comment: Thank you. Problem has been solved when I added the "return"

Answer (score 3):

You can chain them in order by returning them:

```
$.when(a()).then(function() {
    return b();
}).then(function() {
    return c();
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Done!");
});
```

Comment: You can pass these functions directly without wrapping them into an anonymous function.

Comment: But nor a,b or c return promise

Comment: @A.Wolff Good point, I wasn't careful enough. But evidently they should return the promise.

Comment: @NewPHPer - You need to return the ajax call in your a, b, c functions too, otherwise it will try to use `undefined`.

Comment: @MitchelldeRijcke Yes, you are right. Problem has been solved. Thank you for your help:)